# What is the error in mysql statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with names `raspi_E` and `raspi_F` with same structure and the columns 
`id`, `address`, `device_time`.

There are multiple rows with same address in `raspi_E` table but I want the oldest row (with respect to time).

For instance, I have the address `23` multiple times with `device_time` values `2014-08-02 16:00:00`, `2014-08-02 16:00:02`, `2014-08-02 16:00:04`, I want the row containing the oldest `device_time`, that is  `2014-08-02 16:00:00`

Similarly, in the `raspi_F` table, I have multiple rows with same address and I have to get the oldest, in the above example that would be `2014-08-02 16:10:00`.

Now I need to join address `23` at `raspi_E` with time `2014-08-02 16:00:00` and I at `raspi_F` the same address `23` having oldest device stamp `2014-08-02 16:10:00`.

I'm trying to use the following query:

```
SELECT raspi_E.address, MIN(raspi_E.device_time) 
    AS time_D , MIN(raspi_F.device_time) 
    AS time_E 
WHERE (raspi_E.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:00:00' AND 
       '2014-07-31 16:10:00' GROUP BY raspi_E.address) AND 
       (raspi_F.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:03:00' AND 
        '2014-07-31 16:25:00' GROUP BY raspi_F.address) 
       AND raspi_E.address=raspi_F.address
```

I am getting the following error for using the above query

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE (raspi_E.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:00:00' AND
>   '2014-07-31 16:10:0' at line 1

I have used the below query to get oldest row value at raspi_E and it worked fine.

```
SELECT address, MIN(device_time) AS device_time
FROM raspi_E 
WHERE device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:00:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:10:00' 
GROUP BY address ORDER BY `device_time` ASC
```

Comment: Do you get a SQL error? If so, what is it? If not, what is actually wrong?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (raspi_E.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:00:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:10:0' at line 1 @JohnConde

Comment: You'll find it easier to debug your query if you format it half-decently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you were having problems with where / group by... this should do the trick for you...

```
SELECT
      OldestE.Address,
      OldestE.ETime,
      OldestF.FTime
   from 
      ( SELECT 
              E.address, 
              MIN(E.device_time) ETime
           from
              raspi_E E
           where
              E.Device_Time between '2014-07-31 16:00:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:10:00'
           group by
              E.address ) OldestE
      JOIN ( SELECT 
              F.address, 
              MIN(F.device_time) FTime
           from
              raspi_F  F
           where
              F.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:03:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:25:00' 
           group by
              F.address ) OldestF
         ON OldestE.Address = OldestF.Address
```

Comment: @Kroods, glad it worked, but what about it's performance time... should have been very fast with index on (address, device_time).  What were you getting lost on that you had hard time trying to understand.

Comment: Oh, I have put up index as only id, I will add address and device_time as indexes then. I learned three things, initially I thought you mistakenly typed OldestF instead of raspi_E and secondly you have used E.Device_time with D capitalized, I thought it may not work and thirdly I use AS Keyword for aliasing.

Comment: @Kroods, some engines don't like the "AS" keyword and consider it optional, just an FYI for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing your `FROM` clause and a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT raspi_E.address, 
MIN(raspi_E.device_time) AS time_D , 
MIN(raspi_F.device_time) AS time_E 
WHERE (raspi_E.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:00:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:10:00' GROUP BY raspi_E.address) AND (raspi_F.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:03:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:25:00' GROUP BY raspi_F.address) AND raspi_E.address=raspi_F.address
```

should be:

```
SELECT raspi_E.address, 
MIN(raspi_E.device_time) AS time_D , 
MIN(raspi_F.device_time) AS time_E 
FROM raspi_E 
INNER JOIN raspi_F USING <Whatever_key>
WHERE (raspi_E.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:00:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:10:00' GROUP BY raspi_E.address) AND (raspi_F.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:03:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:25:00' GROUP BY raspi_F.address) AND raspi_E.address=raspi_F.address
```

Comment: you have added FROM raspi_E, but I am also using raspi_F

Comment: The above query resulted `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY raspi_E.address) AND (raspi_F.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:03:00'' at line 1`

Comment: I want to join by raspi_E.address=raspi_F.address and it's at last, I am understanding INNER JOIN to know what should I put at <Whatever_key>

Comment: I tried `"SELECT raspi_E.address, 
MIN(raspi_E.device_time) AS time_D , 
MIN(raspi_F.device_time) AS time_E 
FROM raspi_E 
INNER JOIN raspi_F ON raspi_E.address = raspi_F.address
WHERE (raspi_E.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:00:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:10:00' GROUP BY raspi_E.address) AND (raspi_F.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:03:00' AND '2014-07-31 16:25:00' GROUP BY raspi_F.address) "` resulted in `1064 - You have an error in your SQL  ***right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY raspi_E.address) AND (raspi_F.device_time BETWEEN '2014-07-31 16:03:00''`